# Django inherited models are not fully deleted

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have a model inheritance in django something like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField (max_length = 255, unique = True)

class B(A):
 desc = models.CharField (max_length = 255)
```

and when doing delete on B it leaves a trail of "garbage" entires of A behind.

```
obj = B.objects.create(name = "My", desc = "left overs")
obj.delete()
```

now I cant change the model to have t 1to1 FK to A instead of inheritance because it is an already running software.
Is there any good way to do a proper delete?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in this case what you have is two tables, with no relation to each other.

Inheritance does not mean a FK relationship; it just means, quite literally:

> copy all the column definitions from the inherited table, so I don't
>   have to write them again

Inheritance still creates the original table, unless you pass `abstract = True` to the parent model.

To permanently solve this problem, you need to do a database migration, and then either [a] delete table *`A`*, and add `abstract = True` to its definition or [b] create a proper foreign key relationship.

For now, what you can do is find all *`A`*'s that don't have any *`B`*'s and delete those. Unfortunately there is no trick to this, you'll have to do it in a very inefficient way:

```
for obj in A.objects.all():
   if not obj.b_set.all():
      obj.delete()
```